# Component sending undefined via props, because it is mounted before a database query ends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I have a problem related to the asynchronous world with react native.

I need to perform a database query, this query returns me a city vector, this vector should be sent to a picker via props.

The problem is: I perform the query within the ComponentWillUpdate function (by default it's the first function to call before mounting the screen). But even using componentWillMount the component (picker) is being assembled and sending undefined via props.
The data that should be sent is not being processed on time.
The flow of my program is being:

Starts the query (componentWillMount) -> rendering components (render) -> End of Query.

Is it possible to pause the screen mount until the query in ComponentWillUpdate ends?

I tried using async but dont work.

```
async componentWilldMount() {
        try {
            await axios.get(`${server}/getdata`)
                .then(
                //code
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                //handle error
                })
        } catch (err) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing with the information fetched? Are you setting state with it?

Comment: I am storing the data in a global variable and sending this variable via props to the component.

Comment: My approach would be to either use state for that (on state change new props are going to be passed down and everything will rerender) or use redux and store it in redux (if you use redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to pause or stop the rendering the component. What you can do though is to set some property in your state like let's say `data`. So in your constructor you will have omething like that:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        data: null
    }
}
```

Then in your componentWillMount or even better componentDidMount you do:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`${server}/getdata`)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                data: response
            })
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
            //handle error
        })
```

Last step is to render depending on your data so in your render method:

```
render() {
    if(!state.data) {
        return null;
    }

    <SomeComponent data={this.state.data} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** : Use `isReady` flag in the parent component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({value: "bbb", isReady: true});
    }, 5000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isReady && <Child value={this.state.value} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.value}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```